# Angular factory $http get data for multiple pages and global variable

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic and Angular to build a simple app and have a question about my factory and global variables.

I've a JSON file containing data that every page on the app will need to use. Every page in the app will also need access to the device's lat/long.

Currently, in the controller for each page, I am calling in the data and waiting until the promise has resolved before proceeding with the data. On each page, I am also requesting the lat long in the controller for each page.

This all seems a little wasteful since the data will not change between pages and it seems sensible to set the lat long once globally (and then update this with watchPosition, with a callback to update the called in data when the location changes) rather than having to get the location and set it on each pages $scope.

The data is a small (~20) list of locations, each with a lat long. I want to calculate the distance of each of the locations from the current lat long, updating this in the data as the position changes (the callback from watchPosition). My app has 2 pages. One with a list of locations and one showing the locations on a Google map. Both use the same data.

Should I be storing these on the $rootScope or is this considered bad practice? Am I thinking about this in the wrong way? Should I continue on the current path?

Currently, my controllers look like:

```
.....
    .controller('HarboursCtrl', function($scope, Harbours) {

  var harboursPromise = Harbours.all();
  $scope.harbours = [];

  $scope.position = 'Trying to find your location...'

  if (navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
      $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.position = position.coords.latitude+", "+position.coords.longitude;
      })
    })
  } else {
    $scope.position = "Sorry, we can't get your location";
  }

  harboursPromise.then(function(response){
    console.log('response from controller', response);
    $scope.harbours = response.harbours;  
  });
  // $scope.harbours = Harbours.all();

  $scope.remove = function(harbour) {
    Harbours.remove(harbour);
  };
  $scope.getTimes=function(n){
    return new Array(n);
  };
})


.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, Harbours) {
  $scope.position = 'Trying to find your location...'

  if (navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
      $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.position = position.coords.latitude+", "+position.coords.longitude;
      })
    })
  } else {
    $scope.position = "Sorry, we can't get your location";
  }

  var harboursPromise = Harbours.all();

  harboursPromise.then(function(response){
    console.log('response from controller', response);
    $scope.map = { center: { latitude: 51, longitude: 0 }, zoom: 10 };
    $scope.harbours = [];
    $scope.harbours = response.harbours;  
    console.log($scope.map.harbours);
  });

    });
.....
```

And my service looks like:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('Harbours', function($http, $q) {
  var harbours = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '../data/harbourData.json'
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      deferred.resolve(data);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      deferred.reject(status);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }
  return {
    all: harbours,
    get: function(chatId) {
      for (var i = 0; i < harbours.length; i++) {
        if (harbours[i].id === parseInt(chatId)) {
          return harbours[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: why `$rootScope`? you can use factory or service to share data between controllers and services.

Comment: @MudasserAjaz Rootscope was just my initial thought. I'm still very much an angular virgin and don't know best practices yet so looking for suggestions. Cheers

Comment: can set `cache:true` for the $http request --or-- If using ui-router can do one resolve at top level of app routing and it will be available for all descendent states

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your data going to be static? If so, it might be better to write a constant instead of using $http/$q.

```
angular.module('myModule')
    .constant('locations', {
        firstItem: {
            lat: 'someValue',
            long: 'someValue'
        },
        etc: {}
    });
```

So you don't have to make a call every time. If the data is dynamic, you can always cache the value in your factory like so:

```
.factory('myFactory', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
    var harbors = /* resolved object with data */;
    return {
        all: harbors,
        get: function(name) { return harbors[name]; }
    };
});
```

tldr; factories are singletons, so any data cached in them should be availbe anywhere in the app without needing to recall the $http service.

*** EDIT ***

The way I would likely approach this is to create a separate factory to cache any data I need to reuse and write an API factory that helps cache it. So,

```
.factory('appData', [function() {
    var cache = {};

    return {
        set: function(location, payload) {
            cache[location] = payload;
        },
        get: function(location) {
            return cache[location];
        },
        reset: function() {
            cache = {};
        }
    };
}])
.factory('callAPI', ['$http', '$q', 'appData', function($http, $q, appData) {
    return {
        endpoint: function(url, payload, method, cache) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({
                method: method,
                url: url
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.reject(status);
            });
            /** cache must be a string */
            appData.set(cache, deferred.promise);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}])
```

This also maintains separation of concerns within your application.

Comment: Ultimately, the data will be provided by an API so caching it would be preferable. If possible, could you show how I could cache my data in my factory example and then access it in the controllers? (appreciate it's a big ask)

Comment: OK, I updated my answer with how I would likely approach it. You could also use the same pattern of the appData factory, but check first if appData[cache] exists and if so, grab the data and if not, make the request. There are myriad ways to accomplish this.